# PDO Connection to SQL Server Times Out

Tags: php, sql, pdo, visual-studio-2013

PDO is beginning to get me down.  My php code keeps falling over at this line :-

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=127.0.0.1,1000;Database=Database.mdf', 'root', '');
```

and I have no idea why.  It generates the following error message....

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. ' in 
E:\Website\DataValidation.php:5
```

Seem to be spending all my time trying to connect to a database before I can even start using the data inside.

FYI, I have tried with and without the ".mdf", as well as with and with the port at the end of the IP address.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your server from something else?  Do you have some GUI client that you use and can that connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conn = new PDO(
          'sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=c:\db.MDF','root', '');
```

If necessary, you can create a `LocalDB` instance with `sqllocaldb.exe`. You can also use `sqlcmd.exe` to add and modify databases in a LocalDB instance. For example:

```
 sqlcmd -S (localdb)\v11.0.
```

You shouldn't have to specify the Database name, but if you want to:

```
$conn = new PDO( 
     'sqlsrv:server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDBFileName=c:\db.MDF;Database=myDb',
     'root', '');
```

Comment: That's great, got me past that error.  Just got to work out why I can't get any results from my queries now.  lol